# ARM assembly loop

Tags: assembly, for-loop, arm

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  a[i] = b[i] + c[i]
```

What does the ARM assembly for this high level language look like?

Edit: 
I'm also assuming the base address of A is in R8, the base
address of B is in R9, and the base address of C is in R10
and A,B,C are all int arrays

Much appreciated

I tried:

```
MOV  R0, #0  ; Init r0 (i = 0)

Loop:

        a[i] = b[i] + c[i]   //How to fix this? 

        ADD  R0, R0, #1 ;Increment it

        CMP  R0, #1000 ;Check the limit

        BLE  Loop  ;Loop if not finished
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what you're asking here - ARM style Assembly and Android programming are two entirely different things; Android is VM style environment like Java; you can't use Assembly because the code is interpreted by the runtime, not run directly on the processor.

Comment: Regarding your edit; what did you try that ASM in; what software/device are you using ?

Comment: It's not necessarily for Android. I just want experience with the ARM assembly as it's run on mobile devices..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this high level language doesn't have anything conflicting with C, you can use an arm C compiler to create assembly code from your snippet. For example if you have the following in test.c,

```
void test() {
        register int i asm("r0");
        register int *a asm("r8");
        register int *b asm("r9");
        register int *c asm("r10");

        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
        }
}
```

you can run

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -O0 -S test.c
```

to create a test.s file, which will contain assembly code for your test function as well as some extra stuff. You can see how your loop got compiled into to assembly below.

```
<snipped>
.L3:
        mov     r2, r8
        mov     r3, r0
        mov     r3, r3, asl #2
        add     r3, r2, r3
        mov     r1, r9
        mov     r2, r0
        mov     r2, r2, asl #2
        add     r2, r1, r2
        ldr     r1, [r2, #0]
        mov     ip, sl
        mov     r2, r0
        mov     r2, r2, asl #2
        add     r2, ip, r2
        ldr     r2, [r2, #0]
        add     r2, r1, r2
        str     r2, [r3, #0]
        mov     r3, r0
        add     r3, r3, #1
        mov     r0, r3
.L2:
        mov     r2, r0
        ldr     r3, .L5
        cmp     r2, r3
        ble     .L3
        sub     sp, fp, #12
        ldmfd   sp!, {r8, r9, sl, fp}
        bx      lr
<snipped>
```

Now the problem with this approach is trusting the compiler generates the optimal code for your study, which might not be always the case but what you'll get is fast answers to your questions like above instead of waiting for people :)

-- extra --

GCC allows you to put variables into certain registers, see [related documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html).

You can get arm instruction cheat sheet [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf).

Newer versions of GCC creates better arm code as one would expected. Above snipped is generated by version 4.4.3, and I can confirm [Linaro](https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro)'s 4.7.1 proves my claim. So if you take my approach use the most recent tool chain you can get.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/ch-5.html

```
;Print characters 32..126 using a FOR loop-type construct

;R0 holds the character
MOV  R0, #32  ;Init the character
.loop
SWI  WriteC  ;Print it
ADD  R0, R0, #1 ;Increment it
CMP  R0, #126 ;Check the limit
BLE  loop  ;Loop if not finished
;
```

Comment: Dose of salt required here; this source comes from a book written in 1987; theres a good chance it is not applicable to an ARM based android device in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  a[i] = b[i] + c[i]



mov r0,#0x2700
orr r0,#0x0010
top:
ldr r1,[r9],#4
ldr r2,[r10],#4
add r1,r1,r2
str r1,[r8],#4
subs r0,#1
bne top
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon @alpera 's answer - you could also unroll the loop to do 4 ops at once - although whether you get a performance benefit depends whether the memory access or the pipeline stall around the branch is the bigger effect

```
mov r11,#0x2700
orr r11,#0x0010
top:
ldmia r9!, {r0-r3}
ldmia r10!, {r4-r7}
add r0,r0,r4
add r1,r1,r5
add r2,r2,r6
add r3,r3,r7
stmia r8!, {r0-r3}
subs r11,#4
bne top
```

If you have NEON unit handy, we could do it that way too - in which case it will parallelize  the loads, stores and adds - in effect reducing the problem to 5 instructions that perform two iterations of the loop at once.

A C compiler is will not generate code this tight by default (or paralleize for NEON) as it must assume that the buffers used for reading and writing (r8,r10 and r11) can potentially overlap - hence a write through r8 might immediately be read in the next iteration of the loop through r9 or r10.  You can use the `restrict` (`__restrict` in C++) modifier to tell the compiler that this is not the case.